# can't connect sqlite with EF6 wizard

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

I used vs2017 
and installed sqlite & EF6 from nuget 
and used this Extensions 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox

and istalled 
sqlite-netFX46-bundle-win32-2015-1.0.108.0

But these problems show me while using the wizard:

**Test conn**

[image: test conn]

**Error conn**

[image: error conn]

Please help me.

Comment: Maybe you are facing this? https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/issues/8

Comment: hello bro -  ErikEJ
Do You found a solution for this problem ?

Comment: Did you read the issue. It has some proposed workarounds, otherwise wait for VS 15.8 preview 4...

Comment: thank you
I will wait for updates
My version 15.7.1